# Using variable assignment vs repeating method

Tags: c#, string, performance

I would like to know. What is the most performant or correct way to write code between repeating a method or using a unique assignment an assignment

```
 // Solution 1
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Files[m].Trim()))
 {
     Attachment oAttch = new Attachment(Files[m].Trim());
     Msg.Attachments.Add(oAttch);
     Log.LogAttachment(Files[m].Trim());
 }

 // Solution 2
 string file = Files[m].Trim();
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(file))
 {
     Attachment oAttch = new Attachment(file);
     Msg.Attachments.Add(oAttch);
     Log.LogAttachment(file);
 }
```

I prefer solution 2 and I thing this is the correct way to write code. But I would like to know if I'm missing something, something I don't know about the compiler, about `C#`.

Comment: #2 is (minimally) more performant, and also (importantly) more readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The single assignment is mostly preferred i**f the value does not change along the way**, that is, your solution 2. This is because repeating the method will increase the time overhead to call and re-call the method for the **same** result. The second benefit for this use is likely a smaller amount of code since you do not write `.Method()` multiple times.

But if a method produces **different** results every time it is called, like `Random.Next()`, then you have to repeat the method calling.

So the key here is really to know if a method re-calling produces any difference.